# can you download uefi directly from ami instead of from motherboard manufacturer

Tags: motherboard, uefi

```
kernel: DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: Your BIOS is broken; bad RMRR [0x00000000430b2000-0x00000000430b4fff]
```

I expect the UEFI firmware is not really that badly broken, else this is a frivolous question, but I would like to know if you can download the UEFI firmware for the ASRock motherboard directly from AMI to get the newest one?

- Of course, usually, they tell you to get the UEFI firmware from the motherboard manufacturer, which includes the AMI UEFI firmware plus their customizations

If you flash the image provided by AMI, what happens to the customizations from ASRock?  Is it even possible to get UEFI firmware from AMI as a free download?

Comment: There's no such thing as vanilla build of firmware from UEFI vendor, as yes every board model needs a certain degree of "customization". If that's not the case projects like coreboot will probably be as popular as Linux.

Comment: it looks like the manufacturer has no intention of updating the UEFI any more.  So I guess that means I'm out of luck, no?

Comment: Yeah that's a pretty typical case. They usually don't care anyway as long as most things seem to work fine (with Windows). Besides, many UEFI vendors produce crappy firmware anyway.

Comment: You can generally only get UEFI firmware for a board from the board's OEM, as UEFI firmware images are digitally signed by the board's OEM, and checking for a digital signature is the first step of the UEFI flash process - if the digital signature doesn't match what it should, the UEFI installer exits before even moving to the phase where flashing begins.